# mifare ultralight c

Tags: usb, microchip, rfid

i am tired of searching information about this and finding nothing about it, so i am here looking for some professional help. I wanna know if a RFID mifare ultralight c chip can be connected to the copper wires of a micro usb (GND, Sense, d+, d−, and vcc), and with this, can i transfer data from a smartphone, through the micro usb to the rfid chip with an app? or just the only way to write data in the chip is with a rfid reader/writer ? please i need this information as soon as posible. sorry if my english is not good, im from Argentina, thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mifare Ultralight C RFID chips don't have any kind of USB port. They are only accessible via RFID/NFC.

Comment: what if a connect the antenna of one of this chips with a 3.5 jack, could i write data in it through a smartphone app?

Comment: and i know that this chips dont have a usb port, my question was if there is some way to interconect the antenna or the metal parts of the chip with the wires of a micro usb, so i can send information to the chip via usb

Comment: To write to an NFC chip, you need an NFC read/writer. This can be a separate box or you could use a smartphone to write to the tag. There is no other way ! The NFC tag chip HAS NO PINS !!!

Comment: and what about the rfid chip? has it pins??

Comment: @arguelloigna Yes, it has pins. Two exactly. That's where you connect the antenna to. Sorry, no USB, really.

Comment: what about adding a RFID tag or a nfc tag in a smartphone without nfc technology? is this possible?

Comment: @arguelloigna "But what if..." kind of questions won't you lead further to any kind of solution.